# How to properly encode image URL with equal sign for Facebook open graph tag

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook

I have a page with an Open Graph image tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://childhumor2.homeip.net:9009/_ah/img/RYCF7Ty7wODp9R-N_QIWYA===s200"/>
```

The image is a GAE blob and the URL comes from calling `get_serving_url`.  The URL works fine normally.

Now, if someone likes this page, the thumbnail image that is shown in the newsfeed is broken.  Only a blank 1x1 image is returned to the browser.

Inspecting the FB page, the generated HTML is:

```
<img src="http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=6b635a7f80252e93c6b28e2dbe4ad440&amp;w=90&amp;h=90&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fchildhumor2.homeip.net%3A9009%2F_ah%2Fimg%2FRYCF7Ty7wODp9R-N_QIWYA%3D%3D%3Ds200" class="img">
```

When viewing the liking user's news feed for the first time, I see FB hit my server for the image:

```
INFO     2010-11-14 21:33:17,701 dev_appserver.py:3283] "GET /_ah/img/RYCF7Ty7wODp9R-N_QIWYA%3D%3D%3Ds200 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

It is obvious that there is a URL encoding problem with the equal signs in the URL but I have no idea who is at fault here.

- Should FB be unescaping %3D before calling back to my server for the image?
- Is GAE not properly handling an encoded URL?
- Should I be encoding the URL in the Open Graph tag somehow?  (I tried urllib.quote-ing it with the same results.)

To make things more confusing, the [Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) retrieves the image properly.  Also if doing a FB share on the page, the thumbnail preview will be shown correctly.  This leads me to believe this is a bug with the safe_image.php script FB is proxying/caching the image with.

Comment: As of 3/29/11 Facebook fixed this bug.  http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL linter says everything is working correctly, then you are most likely correct that it is a bug with Facebook. I would recommend searching through their existing bugs to see if you can find one that exists, and if not post a new bug. There are currently about 4,300 platform bugs open so it is certainly not unheard of that something is broken. Facebook Bugs: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/

Comment: Make that 4301 bugs... ;) Filed this at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13632

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the case that Facebook should be unquoting the value so that it matches the original og:image you listed, and you should write a bug for that (as Nathan suggested).

However, technically speaking `%3D` and `=` have the same meaning in the path section of a URL and should be treated equally so that might also be bug worthy on the GAE side of things. In this case you probably want to `urllib.unquote()` the path when handled on GAE. (perhaps you could simply redirect to the unescaped version)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no options on the GAE side.  It generates URLs like http://lh4.ggpht.com/n6Tg_8uEu-nS_5ugZ4L5FpFwZ4koEozGfgpo3B84hjxcGRENdX31xzW_r7lD2u7lEd99hxn7jiRULxKA4D8=s400 that go directly to the Google Image Serving Service.  I am only able to see the actual request from FB when running on the local development server.

Comment: Regarding escaping, my reading of RFC 3986 section 2.2 is the "=" is a reserved character and escaping is not valid.

Comment: @cope360 escaping is exactly what you are supposed to do with reserved characters when not used for their reserved usage (ie: ?query_param=data). A strict interpretation is that '=' is reserved only after a '?' in a URL but a general interpretation is that it's reserved everywhere. The difference between those two is where you are having trouble. GAE is expecting the latter, Facebook the former.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, don't use the Google Image Serving Service.  Instead write a handler to retrieve the blob from the datastore, transform it, and stream it back to the client.  This allows you to construct a simpler URL that will not be munged by Facebook.

[Example from GAE Docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/overview.html#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore):

```
class Thumbnailer(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = self.request.get("blob_key")
        if blob_key:
            blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)

            if blob_info:
                img = images.Image(blob_key=blob_key)
                img.resize(width=80, height=100)
                img.im_feeling_lucky()
                thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)

                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
                self.response.out.write(thumbnail)
                return

      # Either "blob_key" wasn't provided, or there was no value with that ID
      # in the Blobstore.
      self.error(404)
```